# Java String to array of bytes wrong conversion

Tags: java, string, type-conversion, arrays

I have a client server Java code and the client is reading in a string "input" and it should then decrypt it, the decryption function needs an array of bytes, so I need to convert the string to array of bytes, which is done using "getBytes()" function, however it seems that this function is modifying the String! How can I convert the string into an array of bytes without changing its content.

```
   String input = inputline.substring(66, inputline.length());
   System.out.println("Read message +"+input+"+");
   byte[] bx = input.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
   System.out.println("Read message +"+bx.toString()+"+");
   System.out.println("Read message +"+bx+"+");
```

the output of the code snippet is as follows:

Read message +[B@161cd475+

Read message +[B@4e25154f+

Read message +[B@4e25154f+

Comment: Can I clarify if `Read message +[B@161cd475+ ` is valid for the String 'input' or not?

Comment: @AlvinBunk  Yes, "[B@161cd475" is the text needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try writing a for loop to print out the results.  I believe Java is spitting  out a random memory value for your output.

```
(int i = 0; s <= bx.length;i++)
{
 System.out.println("Read message +" + bx[i].toString() + "+");
 System.out.println("Read message +" + bx + "+");
}
```

Not sure if my for loop is correct, but it may give you something to work with.  I hope this helps.

Comment: I got a compilation error "byte cannot be dereferenced"

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. I needed to make a String object from the byte array...

```
String inputline = "[B@161cd475";
String input = inputline.substring(0, inputline.length());
System.out.println("Read message +"+input+"+");
byte[] bx = input.getBytes();

// Convert to String object
String tmp = new String(bx);
// Print statements.
System.out.println("Read message +" + tmp + "+");
```

Comment: Thank you, your code outputs the correct output, but I need the byte array "bx" to contain the same values as the String  "[B@161cd475" currently it contains "[B@4e25154f" which is not what I want.

Comment: Maybe do you mean you should be storing as a char[] array. Since storing as byte[] will store as numbers... (decimal specifically).